# End session of inactive user using Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, usersession

I have created a powershell script to get Inactive users from AD with high cpu usage, but now I want to end the session of those Inactive users without disabling the account.
I'm unable to get session Id of inactive users

Can anyone help me to end this inactive user sessions?

Comment: Are these interactive sessions, RDP sessions, or WinRM sessions?

Comment: Please check this it may help you : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/290472/how-to-terminate-session-once-user-away-in-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean by 'inactive user sessions', they are using remote desktop, and you want to log them off the ts / rdp session?

Here are links to PowerShell scripts to log people off RDP Sessions

[Powershell command to kick disconnected users off a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385614/powershell-command-to-kick-disconnected-users-off-a-server)

[Powershell Log Off Remote Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192746/powershell-log-off-remote-session)